# The same divs for several references and duplicate results (Jsoup)

Tags: java, jsoup

Today, faced with the problem, using the JSoup library. The website contains the required data, but there are the same divs that without classes, but with 'style'. Need to get the number of the width.

```
<div style="height: 12px; width: 196px; background-color: #5C1; float: left; border-right: 1px solid #111;"></div>
```

There are two cases: 1. The text appears, but with one div; 2. The text appears on all divs, but making a lot of duplicates and is considered as a new line.

```
try{
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.lolking.net/summoner/euw/34201718").get(); //Random player
        Elements elem = doc.getElementsByTag("div");
        Scanner scn = new Scanner(elem.toString());
        while(scn.hasNext()){
            String res = scn.nextLine();
            if(res.contains("<div style=\"height: 12px; width: ") && res.contains("px; background-color: #5C1; float: left; border-right: 1px solid #111;\"></div>")){
                if(sd == 0){ //So flooding was not. I understand that this can be a problem, but if you remove, there will be a flood of other numbers (duplicates) that cannot be removed, because each line of the program perceives as one
                    String t1 = res.replace("                 <div style=\"height: 12px; width: ", "");
                    String t2 = t1.replace("px; background-color: #5C1; float: left; border-right: 1px solid #111;\"></div> ", "");
                    System.out.println(t2); // Get 192... and all
                    sd += 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

All day can't come up with have experienced a lot of solutions, but always came to these two cases. Recently started to learn Java. Thanks.

Comment: not quite sure what you want mate, do you need to find all **div** that have **style** in them?

Comment: I got completely 'style' and left there only the value of the width. I need it with all the same divs that are on the website. But of class they did not specify.

Comment: you need the width  value of  all div that have style as param. right?

Comment: Right. But there is a problem that if to get it all, then each value is specified as one line and duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, you need all the `width` within the `style` from `div` tag.

you certainly can use `Jsoup` to do it:

**Edited code:**

```
    Set<String> known=new HashSet<String>();
    known.add("height: 12px");
    known.add("background-color: #5C1");
    known.add("float: left");
    known.add("border-right: 1px solid #111");
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.lolking.net/summoner/euw/34201718").get();
    Elements elements=doc.select("div");
    for(Element e : elements){
        if(e.hasAttr("style")){
            Set<String> splitted=new HashSet<String>();
            for(String s : Arrays.asList(e.attr("style").split(";"))){
                splitted.add(s.trim());
            }
            if(splitted.containsAll(known)){
                splitted.removeAll(known);
                for(String s: splitted){
                    if(s.startsWith("width:")){
                        System.out.println(s);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I mean divs that contain in style `<div style="height: 12px;` and `background-color: #5C1; float: left; border-right: 1px solid #111;`. These divs are there, green stripes

Comment: @HorrorPink I've edited the code mate, that should work for ya.

Comment: Thank You! Is it possible for each line 'width' to assign a string? Only 5.

Comment: @HorrorPink what do you mean? you mean to remove "width: " part?

Comment: No. For example, on another account I got only 5 lines. This is what I need. Only each line of the result in the variable 'String';